# Clear all TextBoxes texts

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a tabControl that contains many textBoxes, I want to add a button to clear all textBoxes's texts at once, I tried this code:

```
private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox t in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
    {
        t.Clear();
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work, i got this error message :

> *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox*

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Ok thanks you i tried some solutions before i asked here but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
void ClearTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
            ClearTextBoxes(child);
        else
            textBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}

private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to iterate through every Control, some of which are not TextBox controls.

You can use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) to specify which controls you're interested in, instead:

```
foreach (TextBox t in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    t.Clear();
}
```

Comment: i like that! :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me i tried before and i got an error message

Comment: This is the error message: Impossible d'activer les contraintes. Une ou plusieurs lignes contiennent des valeurs qui violent les contraintes de type non null, unique ou de clé externe

Comment: But when i remove this code my application runs without errors, what is the relation between this code and the violation of non null, unique or foreign key constraints ????

Answer (score 2):

you get all controls (not only the TextBoxes) in the foreach loop

try something like this:

```
foreach (Control t in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
{
    if(t is TextBox)
        ((TextBox)t).Clear();
}
```

Comment: Same here. It doesn't work for me i tried before and i got an error message

Answer (score 0):

Not all controls are textboxes. Do it this way:

```
private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var control in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
    {
        if(control is TextBox)
        {
             TextBox t = (TextBox)control;
             t.Clear();
             // or short:
             // ((TextBox) control).Clear();
        }
    }
}
```